# Поиск внутри кортежей, упакованных в список

Tags: python, список, tuple

Есть одна задача на python связанная с поисками внутри кортежей, упакованных в список. Понимаю смысл и алгоритм решения, но не хватает знаний языка.
Изначальная задача такая, Вам дан список контактов, в котором каждый контакт представлен кортежем с именем и возрастом контакта. Завершите программу, чтобы принимать строку в качестве входных данных , искать имя в списке контактов и выводить возраст контакта в формате представленном ниже: Пример входных данных: John Пример выходных данных: John is 31

В случае если контакт не найден, программа выдает "Not found"

есть стартовый код:

```
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]
```

Я дописал туда свой код, вышло нечто такое

```
contacts = [
    ('james', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

res = input()
d=dict(contacts)
if res in (d.keys()):
    a, b = contacts[i]
    print(a + " " + "is" + " " + str(b))

else:
    print("Not found")
```

В общем, не понимаю как позицию кортежа в списке contacts[i] вычислить, чтобы распаковать в a, b переменные верный кортеж. Если скажем подаю на ввод Amy, то i равно 1 и все работает если я i в ручную на 1 меняю, но вот как это сделать программными методами не понимаю. Буду признателен за правильное решение задачи этой, разными способами чтобы я мог понять как вообще с подобной темой работать и находить индекс нужный в листе внутри кортежей по вводу чего-либо.

Answer (score 2):

Просто нужно создать цикл for и перебрать список.

```py
contacts = [
    ('james', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

res = input()
inList = False
for i in contacts:
    if(i[0] == res):
        inList = True
        print("{0} is {1}".format(i[0], i[1]))
if(not inList):
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Спасибо, понятно!

Answer (score 1):

1. Наличие ключа в словаре можно проверять просто через `res in d` (без `keys()`)
2. Если ключ в словаре найден, то он уже и есть ваше `a`
3. `b` - это значение по ключу (значение в словаре, соответствующее этому ключу), получаем из словаря через `d[res]`

Всё, значения получены, индекс этих значений в списке вам и не нужен.

```
contacts = [
    ('james', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

res = input()
d=dict(contacts)
if res in d:
    print(res + " is " + str(d[res]))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Воот! То что мне не хватало, я чуял что есть проще решение чем с поиском индекса

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно через `filter()` и `next()` в списке найти искомый кортеж. `filter()` делает генератор, из которого `next()` тащит первое совпадение по имени. Дальше выводим либо форматированный результат, либо, если ничего не нашли, строку об отсутствии имени.

```
contacts = [
    ('james', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Amanda', 15),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

name = input('Введите имя')
```

Если у нас список из уникальных имен:

```
data = next(filter(lambda x: x[0] == name, contacts), None)
print('Имя: {}, возраст: {}'.format(*data) if data else 'Ничего не найдено')
```

Если список может иметь повторяющиеся имена:

```
data = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == name, contacts))
print('\n'.join(['Имя: {}, возраст: {}'.format(*d) for d in data])) if data else print('Ничего не найдено')
```

Это кстати момент. Если есть повторяющиеся имена, то превращение в словарь их схлопнет по последнему значению:

```
contacts = [('Amanda', 15), ('Amanda', 65),]
```

станут

```
{'Amanda': 65}
```

Comment: Спасибо интересное решение, я даже не думал в эту сторону

Comment: Welcome) Еще немного добавил инфы для ознакомления

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

def get_age(name: str, contacts: list)->str:
    result = "".join(f"{n} is {a}" for n, a in map(iter, contacts) if n is name)
    if result:
        return result
    else:
        return "Not found"

def main():
    print(get_age("John", contacts))
    print(get_age("Angela", contacts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант! Уже через и filter было, теперь и map будет!

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

name = input()

for i in contacts:
 if name in i:
  print(i[0],'is',i[1])
 else:
  print("Not found")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts = [
('James', 42),
('Amy', 24),
('John', 31),
('Amanda', 63),
('Bob', 18)]
name = input()
data = next(filter(lambda x: x[0] == name, contacts), None)
print('{} is {}'.format(*data) if data else 'Not Found')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```py
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

d = dict(contacts)
name = input()
if name in d:
    print(name, 'is', d[name])
else:
    print('Not Found')
```

Comment: Этот вариант уже есть в других ответах, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305849/1365

Comment: Мне этот ответ аж в трех очередях попался... Бывает же.